# Ereasing a particular char from whole std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to clear string from unwanted chars, and I tried to iterate it through a loop like this.

```
for(auto it=numer.begin(); it!=numer.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it=='-') numer.erase(it);
    }
```

The error is: "expected primary-expression before '=' token";
I could, of course, I could do this with [] operator. But I am wondering why it doesn't work.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It should be `*it` instead of `it*`. Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: `it*` makes no sense. You meant `*it`. Also, you should be careful with editing string your are currently iterating, as `erase` will invalidate `it`.

Comment: When calling `erase()` in a manual loop, you MUST update your iterator with the return value of `erase()` since the original iterator will be invalidated. Which means you can't increment the iterator in your loop definition, it needs to be incremented inside the loop body instead, eg: `for(auto it = numer.begin(); it != numer.end(); ) { if (*it == '-')  it = numer.erase(it); else ++it; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all instances of a character from a string, a simple way to do that would be to use the standard erase-remove(if) idiom:

```
numer.erase(std::remove(numer.begin(), numer.end(), '-'), numer.end());
```

See also:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Or [`std::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2) in C++20: `std::erase(numer, '-');`